Upper bound on absolute value of Confluent Hypergeometric Function with real argument and parameters.
A hypergeometic E-function is
$$
{}_pF_q\left(\left.\begin{array}{ll}
a_{1}, \ldots, & a_{p} \\
b_{1}, \ldots, & b_{q}
\end{array} \right\rvert\, \lambda z^{q-p}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(a_{1}\right)_{n} \cdots\left(a_{p}\right)_{n}}{\left(b_{1}\right)_{n} \cdots\left(b_{q}\right)_{n}} \lambda^{n} z^{n(q-p)}
$$
for integers $0 \leqslant p<q$, rational parameters $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{p} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $b_{1}, \ldots, b_{q} \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \mathbb{Z}_{\leqslant 0}$, and an algebraic scalar $\lambda$, where $(x)_{n}=x(x+1) \cdots(x+n-1)$ denotes the rising Pochhammer symbol of a rational number $x$.
In this notation, the confluent hypergeometric function is $_1F_2$ with $b_2=1$. I am interested primarily in bounding the confluent hypergeometric function above by some function for all real or all rational parameters and arguments. Later, I will consider $_pF_q$ in general. I suspect the bound will be of the form $Ce^{|x|}$ where $C$ is a constant dependent on the parameters and argument. Ideally, this constant will decrease rapidly as one of the parameters, or both parameters tend to infinity - perhaps a denominator growing factorially as one or both of the parameters grow.
I am thinking that I will have to use some combination of a known asymptotic expansion for large $z$, and an analysis of the series expansion for small $z$ but I would really appreciate some guidance about how this is to be done correctly. Perhaps we will have to limit the parameters somehow further, but before I do that, I want to know if any nice bound is known.

Is there an integral representation for the function? It is somewhat more general than the standard confluent hypergeometric function.

I should have mentioned that once I am done with the confluent function in particular, I want to go on to deal with other hypergeometric E-functions, which is why I put the general definition up. In my notation, 1F2 is just the usual Kummer confluent hypergeometric function (usually written 1F1). Edited the post.

Your function seems to be kind of a Laplace transform of the generalised hypergeometric function since a factor $1/n!$ is missing from the sum. The Kummer function is ${}_1 F_2$ with $b_2=1$.

Yes, I should have specified $b_2$=1. Edited.

How is this more general than the $,_pF_q$ hypergeometric function? It looks like just a small change in the convention for defining it.

For $1 < a < b$ we have $\left| {}_1F_1(a,b,z) \right| \leq e^{|z|} |z|^{a-b} \Gamma(b) / \Gamma(a)$ in the original notation for the confluent hypergeometric function.

Is that not asymptotic approximation? Could you please say a little more about this bound?

You might be interested in NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions by F. W. Olver, D. W. Lozier, R. F. Boisvert, and C. W. Clark (direct PDF download). They give asymptotic expansions for hypergeometric functions on page $411$ and $412$ for real parameters.

Thank you, I'm aware of it. I'm interested in particular in converting such an asymptotic expansion into an upper bound for all  real parameters and arguments. Is this possible?

Have you considered continued fractions ?
Anyway I posted an extended comment.
Nice question !

Not a full answer , rather some ideas , but too much for a comment maybe
For the case where are all variables are real :
(the maximum modulus principle is useful here )
Let all variables except $p,q,z$ be close to 1.
Let $q> p+1$.
Let $z$ go to $+\infty$ then the brute asymptotic
$$O( \exp( z^{\frac{q-p}{q-p}} ) ) = O( \exp(z) ) $$
should perhaps be a good estimate.
This is based on this question/answer here :
How fast does this grow: $f(x) =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^i}{i!^{1/2}}$ for real $x$?
Where we see that $(n!)^c$ implies $\exp(x^{1/c})$
This is probably the reason why you involved that weird looking " z^{n(p-q)}" in your question in the first place.
So you want a better approximation.
I thought I share this idea.
Another way to arrive at a solution ( what works for the link given anyway ) is perhaps this idea :
https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/fake-function-theory
Although that method there written is not the most powerful version and might not be a more powerful method than the proof in the given first link of MSE here.
Maybe the better methods will appear soon and that might help.

Another idea might be to use the related differential equations and continued fractions.

